# Materialize options not showing in select tag

Tags: html, materialize

The options in select tag is not displaying in materialize css.

```
<div class="row">  
      <div class="browser-default input-field col s12">
           <select name="select_1" id="select_1">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
           </select>
           <label>Materialize Select</label>  
       </div>                            
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
```

I have used  `$('select').material_select();` but still the options did not show.

Any reason for this? How can I show the options in the select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed the below part.

```
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know that feel